Did Holika mentioned in other scriptures, like Narada Purana?
Most of us know that Holika is Hiranyakashipu's sister, but it is not mentioned in scriptures. However, here the Narada Purana mentioning her:-

O Holi, you have been made by people of childish traits who are afraid of blood sucking Ogresses. Hence I shall worship you. Be the bestower of prosperity on the living beings.”

Does she mentioned in other scriptures, like Narada Purana (not as Hiranyakashipu's  sister)?
